# org.hibernate.MappingException Named query not known

Tags: hibernate, jpa, named-query

I have below entity. When I use named query i give org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: ServiceDataTO.findId.
Why?

```
import javax.persistence.*;


@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(
                name = ServiceDataTO.SELECT_ID,
                query = "select serviceId from ServiceDataTO sd where sd.serviceType = :serviceType"
        )}
)


@Entity
@Table(name = "MCI_SERVICE_DATA")
public class ServiceDataTO {

    public static final String SELECT_ID = "ServiceDataTO.findId";

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SDT_ID")
    private Long sdtId;

    @Column(name = "SDT_SERVICE_ID")
    private Long serviceId;

    @Column(name = "SDT_SERVICE_TYPE")
    private String serviceType;
}
```

client code:

```
   Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
   session.beginTransaction();
   List<Long> r = session.getNamedQuery(ServiceDataTO.SELECT_ID).setString("serviceType", serviceType).list();
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: add relevant code of where you use it and get the exception

Comment: Please add hibernate.cfg.xml or similar configuration. Does Hibernate know where entities are?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot add `ServiceDataTO` in hibernate config.